# Nested type without referencing another schema in Mongoosastic

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I want to give a nested field the elastic mapping type "nested" by using Mongoosastic. I also want to specify the `es_type` of the fields in the nested field.

My schema looks like this:

```
const CarOwner = new Schema({
  cars: [{
    name: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      es_indexed: true,
      es_type: 'float'
    },
  }],
});
```

I want this ElasticSearch mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "carowner": {
      "properties": {
        "cars": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "name": { "type": "text"  },
            "price": { "type": "float"  },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only Mongoosastic examples I've found looks like this:

```
var Car = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      es_indexed: true,
      es_type: 'float'
    },
})


var CarOwner = new Schema({
    cars: {
      type:[Car],
      es_indexed: true,
      es_type: 'nested',
      es_include_in_parent: true
  }
})
```

Do I have to create a subschema or is there any way I could use Mongoosastic to create the mapping I want?

Comment: Have solved this issue? If so could you please post the answer?
I am stuck in simlar problem.